# After chkdsk /r windows wont boot and drive C wont show in bios

Tags: windows, windows-10, chkdsk

Lately, I started noticing that the new NVIDIA driver won't be installed, I tried deleting it and restoring it a few times, and one time when I did that somehow the audio driver got damaged (I have no idea how) - I started hearing differently from the usual.

While installing the NVIDIA driver correctly and trying to reinstall the audio driver, I thought it would be a good idea to check disk C, so I checked for a command to scan and repair the disk. I found the command `chkdsk /f` and ran it. The PC asked for a reset and I did. I waited and saw the repair go up to Stage 2 75%, 59% of the total process. Then I didn't notice exactly what happened but I saw that I needed to select a bootable device and restart the PC.

So I restarted the PC and went to BIOS to check for my C drive with the OS, when I noticed it was gone and only disk D was available.

What happened here and why can't I see disk C even thought I "did everything by the book"?

Comment: I'd suspect drive damage, possibly requiring a fresh install… or a new drive - hard to tell from this info alone. You fell for the *'chkdsk will fix my OS'* fallacy. chkdsk doesn't fix the OS, it fixes the file-system, and will sacrifice any & all files to achieve that goal.

Comment: Test the disk with the manufacturer’s disk test app.  You will likely find a damaged disk.

Comment: how can I test the disk if I cant even boot windows or even see it in bios @John

Comment: Get disk manufacturer's disk test app on bootable USB (manufacturer's support site) and check it that way.

Comment: Have a video that explains it? @John

Comment: No. I look up support sites and they should show bootable tools.    If truly stuck, get a new disk and start fresh.

Comment: Yea, thanks, I believe I would just get a new SSD and start fresh. Most of my data is on disk D anyways